# Why am I getting a GitHub action "permission denied" error when deploying to PythonAnywhere despite adding execution permissions

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions, permission-denied, pythonanywhere

I'm having an issue with GitHub actions permission denied error when trying to deploy to PythonAnywhere.

GitHub Actions Deploy to PythonAnywhere Error Message:

```
Run git update-index --chmod=+x deploy.sh; ./deploy.sh
  git update-index --chmod=+x deploy.sh; ./deploy.sh
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    PYTHONPATH: /home/runner/work/cosmic_cruiser/cosmic_cruiser/
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64/lib
    DEMO_PA_PWD: ***
/home/runner/work/_temp/d8dbb980-ed66-4e73-bbae-b48afa95da3a.sh: line 1: ./deploy.sh: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.
```

main.yml:

```
# This is a workflow to test and deploy our demo app.

name: Demo CI/CD

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  PYTHONPATH: /home/runner/work/cosmic_cruiser/cosmic_cruiser/

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: pa_deploy

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: Set up Python 3.9
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          # Semantic version range syntax or exact version of a Python version
          python-version: '3.9'
          # Optional - x64 or x86 architecture, defaults to x64
          architecture: 'x64'
      # You can test your matrix by printing the current Python version
      - name: Display Python version
        run: python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"

      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install MongoDB
        uses: supercharge/mongodb-github-action@1.8.0

      - name: Install Python packages.
        run: make dev_env

      - name: Run Python tests.
        run: make all_tests
        
      - name: Deploy to PythonAnywhere
        run: git update-index --chmod=+x deploy.sh; ./deploy.sh
        env:
          DEMO_PA_PWD: ${{secrets.DEMO_PA_PWD}}
```

Note: All the files in the repository (such as the README) has all their execute bits set (not sure why). In addition, when I tried to turn it off for deploy.sh I was unable to.

I've tried the following:

1. Check if the execute bit is on for `deploy.sh` (it was):
   `0 -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   757 Feb  1 17:29  deploy.sh`
2. Set the permission via the command line and pushed the changes: `git update-index --chmod=+x deploy.sh`
3. Explicitly set the permission in `main.yml` in the deploy step:

```
      - name: Deploy to PythonAnywhere
        run: git update-index --chmod=+x deploy.sh; ./deploy.sh
        env:
          DEMO_PA_PWD: ${{secrets.DEMO_PA_PWD}}
```

4. Reclone the repository